# How to zip a folder with zip ssh command except specific other folder?

Tags: linux, shell, zip

I have in my **public_html** a folder called **var** with 60GB of content and I need zip **public_html** without this folder beacuse they are very big to compress. I do not want to delete it, simply let it out of the compression operation. I would like to do this with the **zip** command.

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: [Unix zip directory but excluded specific subdirectories](https://superuser.com/q/312301/173513), [how to exclude directories and file zipping a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/q/371579), [How to exclude a directory when zipping files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219101/56041), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -x option which ends with an @

```
zip new_file.zip -r * -x excluded_dir1 excluded_file1 @
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which directories to include and implicitly exclude by doing:

if you have 3 directories to zip (foo bar and var):

```
zip -r public_html.zip foo bar
```

or if you want everything I would do:

```
zip -r public_html.zip $(ls | grep -v var | tr '\n' ' ')
```